# How can i know the latitude(X) and longitude(Y) position of iBeacons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibeacon, estimote

I want to know the position of the iBeacons when the user its near by. i am using the estimote device.

i am able to get the distance within the iBeacons. but How to calculate the position. Please check the below image.

[image]

This is the screenshot from the estimote application.

> Note : i have put my iBeacon device to the estiomote application. they
>   detect the movement of the iBeacons. so how they do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983734/tools-to-determine-exact-location-when-using-ibeacons

Comment: @iPatel: your link is about how to determinate the device location using surrounding beacons, not how to determinate the position of a beacon.

Comment: Your question and comment responses to all the answers seems to indicate that you are mistakenly believing these beacons have an internal capability which they simply do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Wojtek Borowicz, I'm a community evangelist at Estimote.

The beacons do not broadcast their position with X and Y values. They only transmit their ID, sensor data, and information about signal power, based on which the proximity is calculated. The only way to include long/lat and associate it with beacons in your app is to either hardocde their location into the app or fetch it from a database in the cloud.

The radar sceen in the Estimote mobile app doesn't show the location of the beacon. The app does not determine the direction from which the signal is coming, only the proximity. The visual representation is simply an UI thing, to help visualize the idea behind this technology.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the position of beacons, one and only one solution => having the position of each beacon in a database and querying it...

Beacons are dumb, they only know who they are, never where they are.

---

Update

> Blockquote Note : i have put my iBeacon device to the estiomote application. they detect the movement of the iBeacons. so how they do it?

Estimote beacons have accelerometer and temperature sensose

http://blog.estimote.com/post/81380655308/estimote-sdk-updated-with-accelerometer-and-temperature

Comment: +1 for the additional information. but i think  there is something that can detect location. because accelerometer will be in picture when you move iBeacon device. but if u dont move(very first time) iBeacons still he knows the location.

Comment: @SunnyShah - no, they do not.  However, if you record their locations in an external database, then you can look their identifiers up in that to determine the location of any you hear.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. That was never a design goal of iBeacon. You know that the device is near the beacon, that's all you should need to know. To get your location, use CLLocation.

Comment: Hey have you seen the estimote app. they detect the location of estimote how they do it?

Answer (score 1):

iBeacons don't work that way - you can get an estimated distance, but the signal is non-directional, so there is no way of knowing which direction the iBeacon is in.

You can maintain a database of the latitude and longitude where each iBeacon is installed (using the major/minor to identify the beacon in your database) but that won't tell you *precisely* where the phone is in relation to the beacon

Comment: Hey have you seen the estimote app. they detect the movement of estimote?

Comment: I haven't seen that app.  Estimote could have built an accelerometer into their beacon. This could report the movement of the beacon using inertial measurements but is not part of the iBeacon standard

Comment: accelerometer will be in picture when you move iBeacon device. but if  iBeacons at steady position he still reconige. i think there something  additional with estimote device

Comment: Either the phone is moving or the beacon is moving.  Movement will change the received signal strength which allows an estimate of distance but not direction

Comment: moving does not play a role here. if we keep both phone and beacon static position it still detect a position

Comment: It can't detect the position, just a position based on the estimated distance

Comment: Don't be confused by the "radar" like display in the estimote app. The beacons always appear in the same 3 locations on the screen depending on distance